# Bitbucket - Commiting to a new Branch caused issue, not sure how to fix

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch, git-commit

This is the order of actions which caused this problem.

1. Branch created from Master, branch name v1
2. Changes made to this new Branch and pushed
3. I pulled this Branch (after push) and made some changes as well
4. Another user made some changes and pushed (before me)
5. Decided to make a Branch off that Branch, v1_adminui
6. sent a `git fetch` to get the new Branch and issued a `git checkout v1_adminui`
7. `git checkout v1_adminui` complained that I need to commit first because v1_adminui has some files edited which I was working on
8. I issued `git add --all` and `git commit -a -m "Changes to Admin UI"` then did the `git checkout v1_adminui`
9. Now I'm on v1_adminui but I don't have my admin ui commit changes

How do I get my admin ui changes to v1_adminui? It looks like the `commit` happened to v1 so now I'm stuck... Any help would be great please.

Note that I can't push that commit, it needs to be reviewed first before merging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a fairly straightforward fix.  First, look at the documentation for `git cherry-pick` [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).  Then, when you understand what that's doing, take the following actions:

First, delete your local `v1_adminui` branch, since it is, at this point, exactly the same as your `v1` branch.

```
git checkout v1
git branch -D v1_adminui
```

Next, checkout the commit before you added all your adminui stuff

```
git checkout HEAD~1
```

Now, make a "new" `v1_adminui` branch from that commit

```
git checkout -b v1_adminui
```

Next, grab the commit you want from your local copy of `v1` (this assumes that commit is on top of your `v1` branch.

```
git cherry-pick --no-commit v1
```

Now, your index will look as if you had made all of your adminui changes on your `v1_adminui` branch, but haven't yet committed.  Commit those changes:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "<some-message-here>"
```

Now, your `v1_adminui` branch will have all the changes that you wanted to have there.

Lastly, if you want your `v1` branch NOT to have those changes, go back to it

```
git checkout v1
```

and reset them (this assumes that you only made one commit that you no longer want there.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Make sure you are careful with `reset --hard` (check docs [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset))